# rendering two lists within groovy template for play framework 1.2+

Tags: playframework-1.x

I am trying to render a list within a list while using the groovy template for play framework 1.2+.  However, when I use the #{list} tag within a #{list} tag, I do not get the desired result.  Can anyone share how they have approached this in while using the groovy template for play (whether using Groovy or CSS).  Thanks in advance

Comment: Nested lists should be fine. Can you post the part of your template that doesn't do what you expect? Also elaborate a bit on what you expect and what are you getting instead

Comment: My original code was not working because of a missing closing list tag.  thanks to all who contributed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a little sample project with Play 1.2.5 and modified these two files:

**Application.java**:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

  public static void index() {
    List<List<String>> listWithLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    List<String> listInList1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    listInList1.add("1st element in 1st list");
    listInList1.add("2nd element in 1st list");

    listWithLists.add(listInList1);

    List<String> listInList2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    listInList2.add("1st element in 2nd list");
    listInList2.add("2nd element in 2nd list");

    listWithLists.add(listInList2);

    render(listWithLists);
  }
}
```

**index.html**:

```
<ul>
#{list items:listWithLists, as:'listWithinList'}
  #{list items:listWithinList, as:'string'}
    <li>${string}</li>
  #{/list}
#{/list}
</ul>
```